# How to append date to directory path in xcopy

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy

I do have a xcopy statement in bat file..
would you please help me to append today's date to one of directories in destination 
xcopy /S /E /I %sourceFolder% "C:\Shared\copy\%destinationFolder%"

today date is 06072013 so I want my destination look like below

C:\Shared\copy-today's date........

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is method of getting a date stamp that doesn't depend on the regional settings.  Wmic is available in Windows XP Pro and higher.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set datestamp=%dt:~0,8%
set timestamp=%dt:~8,6%
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%

set stamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%

md "C:\Shared\copy-%stamp%"
xcopy here...
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `%date%` in your command:

```
xcopy /S /E /I %sourceFolder% "C:\Shared\copy\copy-%date%"
```

Note: this will keep the date in the original format.

Assuming your local date format is `Fri 06/07/2013` you can format it into `06072013` by cutting up the string like this:

```
%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%
```

So the final command will be:

```
xcopy /S /E /I %sourceFolder% "C:\Shared\copy\copy-%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%"
```

Comment: Love the simplicity and one-line-itude of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
xcopy /S /E /I %sourceFolder% "C:\Shared\copy-%date:/=%\%destinationFolder%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%A in ('echo.%Date%') do set Dest=C:\Shared\copy-%%A%%B%%C
xcopy /S /E /I "%sourceFolder%" "%Dest%"
```